# VBA Double to Time

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have a VBA user form which when I press save after input data it writes to a spread sheet and set my time and date to Now() that is being written to a spread sheet where I  split the now() value into time and date, when I read it back I get the date but my time in decimal format I would like to convert that decimal number back to  time what is the formula for that thank you in advance my decimal number is something like '0.12425576899' so far I found this but it converts that to '00:the minutes on the double:00' here is the code

```
Public Function FromDecimalTime(ByVal t As Double) As Date
FromDecimalTime = TimeSerial(0, Fix(t), (t - Fix(t)) * 60)
End Function
```

Comment: That's a bit hard to follow without any punctuation, but a `Date` in VBA is simply a "decorated" `Double`. I'm guessing? you're just looking for `CDate(t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will convert the `Double` into the `Date` Format. In order to only show the time portion of the date format, use the `Format` function:

```
Sub trythis()
Dim t As Double
t = Now()
Debug.Print CDate(t)
Debug.Print Format(t, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```